# The state is not updated after click in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

I test my React application using Enzyme and Jest. This is my component:

```js
function App() {
    const [state, setState] = React.useState('default');
    const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);
    const [name, setName] = React.useState('ji');
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h2>{state}</h2>
            <h1 className='test'>Helljo</h1>
            <h1 className='test'>Hello</h1>
            <button onClick={() => {
                setState('changed');
                setLoading(true)
            }}>Click</button>
            <Child setName={setName} name={name}/>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Clicking on the button I update the text in `h2` tag.
Below is my test which should test this event:

```js
import { configure,  shallow, mount, render } from 'enzyme';
import App from './App';
import React, {useState} from "react";


describe('Test main component', () => {
  let wrapper = shallow(<App />);
  let setState;
  let setName;
  let setLoading;

  beforeEach(() => {

    setState = jest.fn(x => {});
    setName = jest.fn(x => {});
    setLoading = jest.fn(x => {});

    React.useState = jest.fn()
        .mockImplementationOnce(state => [state, setState])
        .mockImplementationOnce(loading => [loading, setLoading])
        .mockImplementationOnce(name => [name, setName])
  });
  
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });
  
  test('should change state on text', () => {
    const btn = wrapper.find("button");
    btn.simulate("click");
    expect(wrapper.find('h2').text()).toBe('changed');
  })
})
```

Running this test I get:

```
Expected: "changed"
Received: "default"
```

Why do I get this and how to make the test workable?  Note: if I remove the `beforeEach` statement the code works as I expect, but I need to keep that logic, because I need to test the state from my component.

Question: Why does my code not retrieve the expected result and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Because you mock `setState` to a function not do anything so `state` will not update.

```
setState = jest.fn(x => {});
```

You can't mock `setState`. Because it related to change `state` and re-render component logic of `component`. So you should keep the `setState`, focus on another logic.

Comment: please correct me if i understand wrong. You mean that if i mock the setState function i will lose the real functionality of the hook, and if user will trigger a click it anymay won't be changed in the application because the re-render functionality is lost because of mocking the function, am i right?

Comment: Yes. You are correct. The mock function will override it.

Comment: so how to change the logic in my case if i want to test these 2 situations, 1. if the user clicks there should be another state inside h2 tag, 2. to test each state from my component. Is there a solution to mock in another way each state, or which will be the solution to test if each state from my component was updated ?

Comment: You did situation 1. situation 2 will do like situation 1. Read more doc about write test in react

Comment: the last question please. Why to be able to mock every state i can't destructure the useState in my component like: import React, {useState} from "react"; and to use it as follow const [state, setState] = useState('default');, but i have to use that like const [state, setState] = React.useState('default'); to be able to test it? I read many articles, but a lot of them say that i just have to use in the last way and that's it, without a clear argument. Could you explain please? Thanks a lot

Comment: could you help please?

Comment: could you please help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69113147/test-when-page-beforeonload-in-reactjs

Comment: can someone please help with this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75669075/react-jest-test-is-not-showing-updated-state